# How to make .net core automatically compress css/js/html when is publish?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Here is some css/js/html compressor like:
https://csscompressor.com/

or
https://javascript-compressor.com/

And I heard that node.js using some module can automatically compress css/js.I wonder that if .net core has something the same.
However I searched nuget and found nothing about that.Is there any other way can do it?Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bundling and minification is already supported out-of-the-box by ASP.NET Core. It uses the `bundleconfig.json` file to configure the process.

You can read more about the process and configuration here:

[Microsoft Docs - ASP.NET Core Minification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/bundling-and-minification?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=visual-studio%2Caspnetcore2x)

Is this what you were looking for?

Comment: Yeah!That's what I need.Whereas I think I need more time to learn it.Thank you!

Comment: correction, it is not supported by asp.net core, the link say "ASP.NET Core doesn't provide a native bundling and minification solution."

Answer (score 0):

I found a easier way to do it by using a middle ware but not the way microsoft showed.

Here is the way:
https://www.hanselman.com/blog/WebOptimizerABundlerAndMinifierForASPNETCore.aspx